# Visual Studio Portable Paths too long

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-code, c#-devkit

we are trying to set up VS Code in Portable Mode with a C# Development Environment.

Now there is a problem with the lengthy paths of the C# Dev Kit. When trying to run Visual Studio Code it tries to run a escape-node-job which lies at:

.\VSCode\data\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csdevkit-1.3.10-win32-x64\components\vs-green-server\platforms\win32-x64\node_modules@microsoft\visualstudio-code-launcher.win32-x64\escape-node-job

Because it is a User-directory the path becomes to long and it runs into an the criptic error:
[error] Error: spawn .\VSode\data\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csdevkit-1.3.10-win32-x64\components\vs-green-server\platforms\win32-x64\node_modules@microsoft\visualstudio-code-launcher.win32-x64\escape-node-job ENOENT
at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:285:19)
at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:506:16)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)

The paths of course has a user-directory in front which then excedes the normal path limit.

How do I get Visual Studio Code to handle its own Extensions in a correct way?

I already tried to Extend the general Path limit for the system but the error still comes up.

Comment: You can try [enabling long paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry#enable-long-paths-in-windows-10-version-1607-and-later).